# Pythagorean quadruple generators with a gcd relation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For non-negative integers $m,n,q,p$ with $\gcd(m,n,q,p)=1$, assume we have:

$$\gcd(mq+np,b)=|nq-mp|$$ 
for some integer 
$$b<mq+np$$ 
and that 
$$8\nmid\,mq+np,$$
$$m+n+p+q\equiv 1\mod 2.$$

Can we show that $b$ always has solutions of either $m^2+n^2$ or $p^2+q^2$?

Comment: You'll notice that `\not |` $\not |$ compiles very badly. You should use instead `\nmid` $\nmid$ for not dividing. And you should actually use `\mid` for dividing - it handles space correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $(m,n,q,p)=(5,4,4,3)$ we have $gcd(m,n,q,p)=1$ and 
$$
gcd(32,b)=gcd(mq+np,b)=nq-mp=1.
$$
Hence every odd $b$ is a solution, and not only $m^2+n^2=41$, or
$p^2+q^2=25$.

Comment: Consider $(1,1,1,2)$ then with $b=1$. (And we haven't considered cases like $p=0$ yet.)

Comment: Question closed.